# Android EditText value replacing hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to have an EditText for 6-digit verification code which should work like this

When empty:
[image]

When filled 2 digit number:
[image]

How to achieve this in my Android app?

Comment: A hint will not do that. You could have a `TextView` behind the `EditText` that contains your "hint", where you modify the text in the `TextView` as the user types. Even then, unless you use a monospace font, getting everything to line up nicely will be difficult. Otherwise, you might need to create your own subclass of `EditText` that draws your hint.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can try this library

https://github.com/ChaosLeong/PinView

```
repositories {
maven {
    jcenter()
}
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.2'
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.chaos.view.PinView
android:id="@+id/firstPinView"
style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:cursorVisible="true"
android:hint="XXXXXX"
android:inputType="text"
android:itemBackground="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
android:textColor="@color/text_colors"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:cursorColor="@color/line_selected"
app:cursorWidth="2dp"
app:hideLineWhenFilled="true"
app:itemCount="6"
app:itemHeight="48dp"
app:itemRadius="4dp"
app:itemSpacing="0dp"
app:itemWidth="48dp"
app:lineColor="@color/line_colors"
app:lineWidth="2dp"
app:viewType="rectangle" />
```